# Find the x in a matrix in OCaml

Tags: arrays, matrix, ocaml

I'm trying to write a function in OCaml that, given a coordinate in a matrix containing entries "u", "d", "l", "r", and "x", returns *true* if following the 'directions' from that coordinate ends at "x", or *false* otherwise.

My strategy is to check if I've visited the current cell before (if so, return *false*), by passing a matrix *t* of bools through, updating the value of the current cell to true.

My current attempt is below (*n* is the sample matrix I'm trying to navigate):

```
let n = [|  [|"u"; "d"; "l"; "l"; "r"|];
            [|"r"; "d"; "r"; "l"; "l"|];
            [|"u"; "r"; "d"; "d"; "l"|];
            [|"u"; "l"; "l"; "d"; "u"|];
            [|"r"; "x"; "l"; "l"; "d"|];
            [|"r"; "d"; "u"; "d"; "l"|]|];;
let xMax = (Array.length n);;
let yMax = (Array.length n.(0));;
let t = Array.make_matrix xMax yMax false;;

let rec f m x y t = 
if x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= (Array.length m) || y >= (Array.length m.(0)) || t.(x).(y) = true 
then false
else (
    if m.(x).(y) = "x" then true
    else (
        t.(x).(y) <- true 
        if m.(x).(y) = "l" then f m x (y-1) t
        else if m.(x).(y) = "r" then f m x (y+1) t
        else if m.(x).(y) = "u" then f m (x-1) y t
        else if m.(x).(y) = "d" then f m (x+1) y t
        else false
        )
    );;
```

Can anyone help with how to fix this? It's the line

```
t.(x).(y) <- true
```

that isn't working (commenting it out makes the function run, but doesn't update the matrix t).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add ';' after 'true', or it won't compile.

Comment: you should always specify the kind of failure you're meeting: compile-time (syntax error, typing error) or runtime error. Best practice imo is to copy the exact error msg of the system to use,  it is easier for others to help you

Comment: Thanks both. I'll bear that in mind for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a semicolon after the `t.(x).(y) <- true` expression. Without the semicolon, you program is parsed by the compiler as:

```
 t.(x).(y) <- (true if m.(x).(y) = "l" then f m x (y-1) t ...)
```